# How to return a value from database in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to return a value from MSSQL server database and storing it in a variable inside JSR223 timer script in Jmeter. However I am getting the following error in log -

**WARN o.a.j.t.JSR223Timer: Script did not return a value
**

This is the code which i have written in the script -

```
try {
        def promoName = ${promotionName}; //extracted the value using JSONExtractor
        log.info("Promotion Name is " + promoName); //not displaying in the log
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ServerIP;databaseName="";integratedSecurity=true","<userId>","<password>");
    String query ="select query";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        vars.put("promotionInstanceId", rs.getString(1)); //The query returns an instanceId which i need to store in a variable and use it later
        log.info("Promotion Instance is " + ${promotionInstanceId});            
    }
    conn.close();
    } 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

Can anyone help me in understanding where i might have gone wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Any reason to use the timer? The warning you're getting is about missing [return keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) as the JSR223 Timer is intended to be used for calculation of virtual user [think time](https://medium.com/@malith.jayasinghe/performance-testing-with-a-think-time-64b6b737e3f9) therefore it should return the value to "sleep" in milliseconds. Given you don't want to introduce the think time it makes sense to go for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead.
2. [Don't inline JMeter functions or variables into the scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as it might cause script misbehavior due to clashing with [GString template](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html) or the variable will be cached and the same value will be returned for the subsequent calls.
3. It is recommended to use JMeter's built-in components and avoid scripting where possible, you can use i.e. [JDBC PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) in order to extract the interesting value(s) and store it(them) into JMeter Variables. Check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article to learn how to execute SQL statements and work with results

Comment: It worked when i used with JDBC Request. The next question like how do i store the return value of the sql query globally using BeanShell Assertion. I tried using like - ${__setProperty(promotionInstanceId, ${PromotionInstanceId_1})}; but i could not retrieve the value in another thread

Comment: PromotionInstanceId is the variable names that i gave while creating the jdbc request

Comment: I repeat point 2: **Don't inline JMeter functions or variables into the scripts**. The relevant substitution would be `props.put("promotionInstanceId", vars.get("PromotionInstanceId_1"));`. Also consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) as [you should be using JSR223 Test Elements instead of Beanshell starting from JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Comment: Okay. My project setup as of now is like i have 2 JsonExtractor to extract 'PromotionId' and 'PromotionName' from the HTTPRequest response data and the 'PromotionInstanceId' is extracted from the JDBCRequest. Then in the BeanShell Assertion I am setting up the values extracted globally so that i can use those values in another thread. I am able to set the sql query value but the json extractor values are not getting set. What might be the reason ?

Comment: In the BeanShell Assertion i have 3 lines -
${__setProperty(promotionId, ${promotionId})}; //extracted from 1st Json Extractor
${__setProperty(promotionName, ${promotionName})}; //extracted from 2nd JsonExtractor
${__setProperty(promotionInstanceId, ${PromotionInstanceId_1})}; //extracted from JDBCRequest query

Comment: Got it. I moved the JDBCRequest query to another thread. Now it is working as expected, but still i could not understand why it was not happening in single thread. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `vars.get` to get variable value

```
vars.put("promotionInstanceId", rs.getString(1)); //The query returns an instanceId which i need to store in a variable and use it later
log.info("Promotion Instance is " +  vars.get("promotionInstanceId"));
```